# %include centos kickstart unable to open input kickstart file

Tags: centos, anaconda

Hi would like to have multiple kickstart files which use a central kickstart file for the bulk of the install and a second file for the small differences. I'm building DVDs for distribution.

The first ks contains small config and has a %include line which points to a common ks file which should do most of the work.

I'm having trouble with %include line.

Fist of all have I understood what %include is for?
Second I think I have the syntax wrong because when I boot I get the following error message:

```
unable to open input kickstart file: Could not open/read file:///mnt/sysimage/media/dvd/ks/common.cfg
```

I am installing from a DVD what is the correct path or syntax to the files stored in a sub directory called /ks/ of the DVD's root?

I have tried the following:

```
%include /mnt/sysimage/media/dvd/ks/common.cfg
%include cdrom:/ks/common.cfg
```

Does anyone have any working examples?

Thanks in advance for your support

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found part of the answer

```
%include /mnt/stage2/ks/common.cfg
```

The dvd is mounted as stage2

However I now get an error message saying it cant read the file

`%%include`

I can see the file and less it if I hit `ctrl + alt + F1`

Does anyone have a working simple example of how this should be written?

Comment: It looks like the file is accessible but not adding to the main kickstart file. Does anyone have a working example of the correct use of %include?

Answer (score 0):

Open your isolinux/isolinux.cfg from the OS and give the ks file path as below . You can enter your kick start option in boot: prompt of dvd

`label 1
  kernel vmlinuz
  append initrd=initrd.img nofb skipddc lang= devfs=nomount ramdisk_size=8192 ks=cdrom:/option1.cfg 1
label 2
  kernel vmlinuz
  append initrd=initrd.img nofb skipddc lang= devfs=nomount ramdisk_size=8192 ks=cdrom:/option2  2
label 3
 kernel vmlinuz
 append initrd=initrd.img nofb skipddc lang= devfs=nomount ramdisk_size=8192 ks=cdrom:/option3.cfg 3`

Then edit `/isolinux/boot.msg` and add the enter the below details

Select installation:

```
   1) option 1    
   2) option 2   
   3) option 3
```